# cannot enforce strict bound ampl

Tags: ampl

I set a variable to `var p > 0;` after it was `var p >=0;` (and a working model) to make sure that I do not get a divide by zero error. Now, while trying to run the model, it gives me the following error:

```
cannot enforce strict bound
context:  var p >  >>> 0; <<<
```

After a quick search, I found that I have to give a low value and not zero to make it work.

```
var p > 0.00001; or var p > 1e-6;
```

however, it still gives the same error. Can you please explain what exactly is the issue here, and how to solve it?
My equation is of the form

> Maximize Z : (quadratic function of p)/p;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimisation in general (and AMPL in particular) generally requires that the feasible region is [topologically *closed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set), i.e. any limit point of the permitted solution space is itself part of the solution space. This means that strict inequalities are generally not permitted as constraints on variables.

To understand why, consider the problem:

```
var p > 0;
maximize OF: 1-p^2;
```

Even though the OF is obviously bounded and can never exceed 1, this cannot be optimised because there is no optimal value of p. For any permitted (i.e. positive) value of p that you might propose, I can improve the objective function by halving p. It's hard to define an optimisation algorithm that deals with a situation where no optimum exists, not even a local optimum!

(Technically, machine precision *does* impose an optimal value of p, where p is the smallest positive number that can be represented in computer arithmetic. But if we want to look at it that way, then effectively we do have a strict inequality, p >= eps, and we're better off acknowledging that explicitly.)

For this reason, constraints on variables generally need to be non-strict inequalities, e.g. replace "> 0" with ">= smallnum".